# Open the settings Page with search string in Android Lollipop with intents

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop

Im trying to open the Settings page with the search query already typed in

Image url:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE5sU.jpg

I know we can open the Settings page through an intent.But is it possible to add an extra for the search query so that it will open the Settings page with the search string already typed in(like it does for email with the email id typed in)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening Settings `Activity` with filering option is not available.

Without filters it will be just:

`context.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));`

But there are more flags to open specific settings so instead of using search string you could use specific one
[Here is full list of available settings pages to open](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/provider/Settings.html)

In your screen you have accessibility things so maybe [ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS) will mach your needs

Comment: I am already using ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS currently.The reason I want to use search is because if you search with the app name the app will come on top of the page and will be highlighted with the ripple effect once the user clicks on the search result. This will be easier for the user to click on rather than manually searching for my app in the Accessibility page(which i am currently doing).

Comment: So going that far is not possible.